# ASP.NET Web API Stack Trace Not Available - UseProblemDetails

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, .net-5

It has been a while since I developed an API so bear with me. I have created a new web API in the new .NET 5.0 framework. I have tried using Hellang.Middleware.ProblemDetails nuget for my error handling middleware. Seems to be working, but I cannot get any stack trace details to show for life the me, is there something I am missing?

I can only get the following details:

> {"type":"https://httpstatuses.com/404","title":"Not
> Found","status":404,"traceId":"00-02c4e89a990c5745bc4250cfad83d5e3-bb8c1dab98b44a44-00"}

Here is relevant code from my startup class:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<CoreDbContext>(op => op.UseSqlServer(AppSettings.DBConnectionString).UseLazyLoadingProxies());
        services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

        services.AddProblemDetails(opts =>
        {
            // Control when an exception is included
            opts.IncludeExceptionDetails = (ctx, ex) =>
            {
                // Fetch services from HttpContext.RequestServices
                var env = ctx.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IHostEnvironment>();
                return env.IsDevelopment();
            };
        });
    }

    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();            
        }

        app.UseProblemDetails();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some information on the request you were trying make as well as your controller and route code? There isn't going to be any exception message with a 404, since it's just a standard response type. If you want to test getting stack trace details, try deliberately throwing an exception within your controller code and see what gets sent in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returned ProblemDetails is for a 404. This wouldn't have a stack trace associated with it. By the looks of it in production if an exception occurs then you will get a raw 500, whereas in development it should render the stack in the developer exception page. Try introducing an obvious exception and see what is returned.

The following link (though outdated) provides some more details on this: https://andrewlock.net/handling-web-api-exceptions-with-problemdetails-middleware/

Answer (score 0):

Usually the 404 is the error you get because the API can't find the method, try to be sure for the url.

For example

```
[HttpGet]  
[Route("api/AnyNameyouWantForRoute/parameter")]  
// your method in controller
```

Your url must be like

```
http://theIpYouChoose/api/AnyNameyouWantForRoute/parameter
```

If you have a typo in this you will not find the method to call and you will get 404

Comment: Try providing an example or method to make your answer clearer :)

Comment: thanks for the advice, i will edit my post in few minutes